# Problemas ao comparar dois endereços IPv6

Tags: c, socket, ipv6

Ultimamente andei trabalhando em diversos "códigos-testes" para exercitar a "cabeça", especificamente códigos envolvendo a *API* de *sockets* do *Unix*. O código mais recente que escrevi foi um simples servidor que recebe uma nova conexão de um cliente a cada 2 segundos. A ideia principal por traz do código era simplismente compara os endereços dos clientes e ver se não eram os mesmos que se conectaram com sucesso em uma conexão anterior.

Eis aqui o código do servidor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define PORT "9009"

short int check_addr(struct sockaddr aux,
                     const struct sockaddr *vet, size_t amount)
{
    short int rv=0;

    struct sockaddr_in *aux4=NULL, *addr4=NULL;
    struct sockaddr_in6 *aux6=NULL, *addr6=NULL;

    if(aux.sa_family==AF_INET){

        aux4=(struct sockaddr_in*)&aux;
        addr4=(struct sockaddr_in*)vet;

        for(size_t i=0; i<amount; i++){

            if(aux4->sin_addr.s_addr==addr4[i].sin_addr.s_addr){

                rv=-1;
                break;
            }
        }

    }else if(aux.sa_family==AF_INET6){

        aux6=(struct sockaddr_in6*)&aux;
        addr6=(struct sockaddr_in6*)vet;

        for(size_t i=0; i<amount; i++){

            if(aux6->sin6_addr.s6_addr==addr6[i].sin6_addr.s6_addr){

                rv=-1;
                break;
            }
        }

    }else{

        rv=-2;
    }

    return rv;
}

void show_addr(struct sockaddr addr){

    char address[1024];

    struct sockaddr_in *addr4=NULL;
    struct sockaddr_in6 *addr6=NULL;

    if(addr.sa_family==AF_INET){

        addr4=(struct sockaddr_in*)&addr;

        inet_ntop(AF_INET,
                  &addr4->sin_addr.s_addr, address, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

    }else{

        addr6=(struct sockaddr_in6*)&addr;

        inet_ntop(AF_INET6,
                  &addr6->sin6_addr.s6_addr, address, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
    }

    printf("%s\n", address);
}

int make_server_socket(void){

    int sockfd;
    struct addrinfo *res=NULL, *ptr=NULL, hints;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

    hints.ai_flags=AI_PASSIVE;
    hints.ai_family=AF_INET6;
    hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol=IPPROTO_TCP;

    if(getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &res)!=0){

        sockfd=-1;

    }else{

        for(ptr=res; ptr!=NULL; ptr=ptr->ai_next){

            if(ptr->ai_family==AF_INET || ptr->ai_family==AF_INET6){

                sockfd=socket(ptr->ai_family, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

                if(sockfd<0){

                    continue;
                }

                if(bind(sockfd, ptr->ai_addr, ptr->ai_addrlen)==0){

                    break;
                }

                close(sockfd);
            }
        }

        freeaddrinfo(res);
    }

    return sockfd;
}

int main(void){

    int sockfd=make_server_socket();

    if(sockfd<0){

        exit(1);
    }

    if(listen(sockfd, 10)<0){

        exit(1);
    }

    int csockfd;
    size_t count=0;
    struct sockaddr *vet=NULL, aux;
    socklen_t addrlen=sizeof(struct sockaddr);

    for(size_t i=0; i<1000; i++){

         csockfd=accept(sockfd, &aux, &addrlen);

         if(csockfd<0){

            continue;

         }else{

            if(check_addr(aux, vet, count)==0){

                count++;
                vet=realloc(vet, addrlen*count);

                vet[i]=aux;

                show_addr(vet[i]);

                close(csockfd);
            }
        }
    }

    close(sockfd);

    free(vet);
    vet=NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Como nem tudo na programação são flores o meu servidor acabou apresentando os seguintes problemas:

**1º** - A função `check_addr()` só consegue notar diferença entre *IPv4*, fazendo assim a aceitação de diversas conexões vinda de um mesmo cliente/ip que usa *IPv6*. Para uma melhor compreensão do problema descrito aqui, veja abaixo a seguinte desmostração:

Aceitando conexões de um cliente usando `IPv6` (`AF_INET6`):

```
zherkezhi@zherkezhi :~/Documents/C$ ./server

2804:d47:1b17:2100::
2804:d47:1b17:2100::
2804:d47:1b17:2100::
2804:d47:1b17:2100::
2804:d47:1b17:2100::
2804:d47:1b17:2100::
2804:d47:1b17:2100::
2804:d47:1b17:2100::
2804:d47:1b17:2100::
2804:d47:1b17:2100::
2804:d47:1b17:2100::
2804:d47:1b17:2100::
```

Aceitando conexões de um cliente usando `IPv4` (`AF_INET`):

```
zherkezhi@zherkezhi :~/Documents/C$ ./server

192.168.1.123
```

No caso acima, eu havia feito o meu cliente tentar se concetar ao servidor 12x usando na primeira vez `IPv6` e na segunda `IPv4`. Com IPv6 apresentou problemas (aquele descrito logo acima) e com `IPv4` o mesmo não ocorreu.

**2º** - A função `inet_ntop()` aparentemente está funcionando apenas com *IPv4*, ou seja, quando se trata de *IPv6* acontece a seguinte situação:

**Cliente**

```
 zherkezhi@zherkezhi :~/Documents/C$ nc 

 2804:d47:1b17:2100:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX 9009
```

**Servidor**

```
 zherkezhi@zherkezhi :~/Documents/C$ ./server

 2804:d47:1b17:2100::
```

Era para imprimir `2804:d47:1b17:2100:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX` e não `2804:d47:1b17:2100::`, ou seja, a imprenssão do endereço está incorreta/incompleta.

Então, qual seria um possível solução para os problemas apresentados acima?

**OBS:** Não postei o código do cliente aqui porque achei desnecessário, já que o meu cliente não passa de uma chamada do `netcat` a cada 2 segundos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Endereços IPv6 normalmente são abreviados para eliminar longas sequências de zeros. Por exemplo:

```
2804:d47:1b17:2100:000:0000:0000:0000
```

é representado por

```
2804:d47:1b17:2100::
```

Você pode fazer testes de normalização de endereços IPv6 [neste site](https://tools.tracemyip.org/IPv6-compression-normalization/)

Não existe uma maneira automática de fazer esta normalização via programa, é preciso escrever código. Veja [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389082/ipv6-address-validation-and-canonicalization) do SO em inglês para ter uma ideia do que fazer.

UPDATE:

você está fazendo a comparação de maneira errada

```
if (aux6->sin6_addr.s6_addr == addr6[i].sin6_addr.s6_addr)
```

porque s6_addr é uma array de 16 caracteres, não é um valor escalar.
O resultado sempre vai ser falso, porque o comando está comparando dois endereços de memória diferentes.

Você deve usar função memcmp:

```
if (memcmp(aux6->sin6_addr.s6_addr, addr6[i].sin6_addr.s6_addr, 16) == 0)
```

UPDATE

É preciso guardar na tabela uma cópia dos endereços recebidos pelo server.
Estas linhas

```
vet = realloc(vet, addrlen*count);
vet[i] = aux; //<----erro no caso de IPv6
```

estão erradas (no caso de IPv6), é preciso fazer uma malloc de uma estrutura sockaddr_in, copiar "aux" para a memória alocada, e guardar o endereço da memória alocada na tabela.

Como fica difícil explicar por palavras, refiz o programa de uma maneira simplificada, contemplando apenas IPv6. Mesmo assim, seria melhor guardar na tabela o resultado de inet_ntop, e não "addr6.sin6_addr.6_addr", porque é muito fácil cometer erros fazendo desta maneira.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define PORT "9009"

static void print_hex(struct sockaddr_in6* addr6)
{
  size_t i;
  unsigned char* buf = (unsigned char*)(addr6->sin6_addr.s6_addr);
  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  {
    printf("%02X|", buf[i]);
  }
}

// retorno
//   0: nao encontrou na tabela
//  -1: encontrou na tabela
//  -2: familia invalida
short int check_addr(const struct sockaddr* addr, struct sockaddr *addrTable[], size_t n)
{
  if (n == 0)
  {
    printf("* primeiro endereco, nao vai verificar\n");
    return 0;
  }

  size_t i;
  struct sockaddr_in6 *addr1 = (struct sockaddr_in6*)addr;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    struct sockaddr_in6 *addr2 = (struct sockaddr_in6*)addrTable[i];
    printf("* comparando enderecos do indice %d\n", i);
    printf("* primeiro endereco: ");
    print_hex(addr1);
    printf("\n");
    printf("* segundo endereco: ");
    print_hex(addr2);
    printf("\n");
    if (memcmp(addr1->sin6_addr.s6_addr, addr2[i].sin6_addr.s6_addr, 16) == 0)
      return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}

void show_addr6(struct sockaddr_in6* addr6)
{
  char address[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
  printf("* show_addr: addr6: ");
  print_hex(addr6);
  printf("\n");
  inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &addr6->sin6_addr.s6_addr, address, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
  printf("* from ntop: %s\n", address);
}

int make_server_socket(void)
{
  int sockfd;
  struct addrinfo *res = NULL, *ptr, hints;

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));

  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

  if (getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &res) != 0)
  {
    printf("* erro em getaddrinfo\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  for (ptr = res; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next)
  {
    if (ptr->ai_family == AF_INET || ptr->ai_family == AF_INET6)
    {
      sockfd = socket(ptr->ai_family, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
      if (sockfd < 0)
        continue;

      if (bind(sockfd, ptr->ai_addr, ptr->ai_addrlen) == 0)
        break;

      close(sockfd);
      sockfd = -1;
    }
  }

  if (sockfd < 0)
  {
    printf("* endereco ip invalido\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  freeaddrinfo(res);

  return sockfd;
}

int main(void)
{
  size_t i;
  int csockfd;
  socklen_t addrlen;

  struct sockaddr addr;
  struct sockaddr *addrTable[1000];
  struct sockaddr_in6* addr6 = (struct sockaddr_in6*)&addr;

  int sockfd = make_server_socket();

  if (listen(sockfd, 10) < 0)
    exit(1);

  for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  {
    printf("*\n");
    printf("* aguardando conexao\n");
    addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    csockfd = accept(sockfd, &addr, &addrlen);

    if (csockfd < 0)
    {
      printf("* erro no accept\\");
      exit(1);
    }

    if (addr.sa_family != AF_INET6)
    {
      printf("* conexao nao e' ipv6\\");
      exit(1);
    }

    printf("* endereco IPv6 do client: ");
    print_hex(addr6);
    printf("\n");

    if (check_addr(&addr, addrTable, i) == 0)
    {
      struct sockaddr_in6* saveAddr6 = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr));
      void* from = &addr;
      void* to = saveAddr6;
      memcpy(to, from, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

      printf("* saveAddr6: ");
      print_hex(saveAddr6);
      printf("\n");
      addrTable[i] = (struct sockaddr*)saveAddr6;
      show_addr6(saveAddr6);
    }

    close(csockfd);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Rodando telnet local o endereço que aparece é :: (estranho, achei que seria ::1), conectando a partir do meu celular:

```
zv@localhost so]$  ./test-ip6
*
* aguardando conexao
* endereco IPv6 do client: 28|04|01|4D|32|80|45|A1|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|
* primeiro endereco, nao vai verificar
* saveAddr6: 28|04|01|4D|32|80|45|A1|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|
* show_addr: addr6: 28|04|01|4D|32|80|45|A1|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|
* from ntop: 2804:14d:3280:45a1:: <-------------------
*
* aguardando conexao
* endereco IPv6 do client: 28|04|01|4D|32|80|45|A1|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|
* comparando enderecos do indice 0
* primeiro endereco: 28|04|01|4D|32|80|45|A1|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|
* segundo endereco: 28|04|01|4D|32|80|45|A1|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|
*
* aguardando conexao
* endereco IPv6 do client: 28|04|01|4D|32|80|45|A1|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|
* comparando enderecos do indice 0
* primeiro endereco: 28|04|01|4D|32|80|45|A1|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|
* segundo endereco: 28|04|01|4D|32|80|45|A1|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|00|
```

Comment: mas no meu caso o meu IPv6 externo não apresenta esses 0's e sim outros valores não 0's. E no caso da falha ao comparar dois IPv6 entre si? Porque a comparação falha?

Comment: Usei a função `memcmp` e não funcionou, continuou aceitando as mesmas conexẽs.